# Why Bootstrap 3 Accordion jquery not worked for me

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me to solve problem related to accordion up and down glyphicon in bootstrap 3.here is my HTML code

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordian" href="#mens">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                                        Dabur
                                    </a>
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="mens" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Hair Oil</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Baby Care</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Oral Hygiene</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Shampoo & Conditioner</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Honey</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Candy-Chocolate</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Chyawanprash</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Balm</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Capsules</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"> Syrup / Health Tonic</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Churan / Digestive Suppliments</a></li>

                                    </ul> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And This is my Jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(document).on('click', '.accordion-toggle', function() {     
    $(".accordion-toggle").each(function() {
        var iconSpan = $(this).find('.glyphicon');
        if ($(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
            $(iconSpan).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
        } else {
            $(iconSpan).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        }
    });
});
});

</script>
```

I tried hard to simulate problem but does't solve,please solve if found any error

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: Please edit your question and edit in a clear problem description. If you don't tell us what happens, we have to assume Pink Unicorns(tm) spawn when you execute this code. This is intended behavior of any code. "Doesn't work" is not a problem description, as it only tells us that this code behaves differently from what you expect, without actually telling us what you see or what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do away with the jQuery altogether by doing it like this:

For this HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-parent="#accordian" href="#mens">
                <!-- add both icons to the dom, we'll chow and hide them with CSS -->
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down pull-right"></span>
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up pull-right"></span>
                Dabur
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="mens" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Hair Oil</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Baby Care</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Oral Hygiene</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Shampoo & Conditioner</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Honey</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Candy-Chocolate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Chyawanprash</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Balm</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Capsules</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Syrup / Health Tonic</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Churan / Digestive Suppliments</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This CSS:

```
.accordion-toggle .glyphicon-chevron-down,
.accordion-toggle.collapsed  .glyphicon-chevron-up{
    display:none;
}
.accordion-toggle.collapsed  .glyphicon-chevron-down{
    display:block;
}
```

[**See it in this demo**](http://www.bootply.com/RvQUpvzFQ2)

Comment: Thanks sir that's i need,rocking formula keep it always.